# Unable to run tests after migrating to junit5

Tags: android, gradle, junit5

I'm running tests on android using gradle and we're migrating our framework to junit5 to take advantage of some of it's tagging and filtering capabilities. I've created the dependencies in my build.gradle files and I'm able to get it to build and run using the gutter icon in android studio, but I'm unable to run my tests from the command line. I get the following error.

```
    * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileTestKotlin'.
 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:testCompileClasspath'.
    > Could not find junit:junit:5.7.0.
      Searched in the following locations:
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/5.7.0/junit-5.7.0.pom
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/5.7.0/junit-5.7.0.jar
        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/5.7.0/junit-5.7.0.pom
        - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/5.7.0/junit-5.7.0.jar
      Required by:
          project :app
```

Here's my build.gradle at the app level

```
plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1' // Latest Plugin Version
    id 'java'
}

allure {
    autoconfigure = true
    version = '2.13.7'  // Latest Allure Version

    useJUnit5 {
        version = '2.13.7' // Latest Allure Version
    }

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.0',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    )
    testRuntimeOnly(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    )
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform(){
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

test {
    systemProperty 'platform', project.findProperty('platform')
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.1'
    implementation "io.appium:java-client:7.2.0"
//    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'junit:junit:5.7.0'
}
```

and here's the build.gradle at the project level.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please show your Gradle build file.

Comment: Added both files to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it. `implementation 'junit:junit:5.7.0'` is a non-existing dependency. Leave it away and it might already work.

Comment: commented that line out and everything works! Cheers!